# Downvoters, downvoters...

Tags: feature-request

I was involved into stupid situation. One person on this site has strange behavior. He has his own opinion (maybe, I hope :) ) and just downvotes without any reasons. I asked, what is going wrong. No answers. As I know he is a famous downvoter on many stackexchange family sites. How do professionals and enthusiasts prevent again so strange persons?

As I understand these persons smooth the general picture by doing so stupid matters. It is a bad luck. No comments.

Comment: I just looked at your activity - nowhere do you ask why people downvoted your answers.

Comment: Real mature with that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Igor, I wouldn't get too worried about it.  Remember, first of all, that down-votes (on answers) are 1/5 the value of a single up-vote.

Second, **assume good faith** (this is one of the [fundamental principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAssume_good_faith) that Wikipedia established to facilitate building a positive community).  In general it is a little impolite to down-vote without comment, but, there can be valid reasons for doing so - if it's an issue where you fundamentally disagree and don't want to be drawn into an argument where you are challenging another person's core beliefs.

Some users will decide to use their 30 votes a day to mostly vote things down - that's fine. It's not necessarily positive, but as a single voice in the community, that's their prerogative. Remember, it's only a single voice.

Comment: @igor I believe the post was closed and locked because of the edit war going on in the original post. It's bad form to call people out and I suspect you know that. See http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/GoodBye before you do anything rash.

Comment: nice post. thanks.

Comment: Agreed, very nice post. Thank you Renesis!